# Ordered Probit with 20+ categories

Tags: logistic, least-squares, probit, ordered-probit

Is there any upper limit on categories I can use for the dependent variable in an ordered probit model? In my current model I have at least 20 categories, but I maybe require more (up to 50). Is this theoretically possible?

Comment: There isn't for an ordered logit model; see Chapter 13 of Frank Harrell's [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/ordinal.html). You can in principle have as many levels as there are observations. I suspect that there's similarly no limit in an ordered probit model, but there might not be efficient numeric implementations as easily available.

Comment: Great! Thanks! That helps a lot! The number of categories will actually be rather small compared to the total number of observations